# Writing Pyspark Dataframe as Parquet to S3 on Databricks just hangs in the middle

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks, parquet

I have a pyspark dataframe with approximately 250 trillion rows. I am trying to write it as parquet in AWS S3 bucket using one of the columns as a partition. But it just hangs in the middle even after running it for 16 hours which is just completely absurd. I am trying to find the most optimal way to achieve this, have not figured out yet. I am trying the basic script like below:

```
df.write.parquet("path", mode = "overwrite", partitionBy = "column-name")
```

Comment: How many cores do you have? What do the logs say?

Comment: The cluster has 20 cores. The log says - "[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 6603776K->912K(6606848K)] 13903733K->7300869K(19831808K), 0.0228745 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]"

Comment: This is not the error though. You will have to provide more context, Spark config, Code, stderr logs..